# What is the best way to populate a multiple select drop down list that has 10,000 rows in Laravel?

Tags: php, optimization, laravel-7

I'm currently looping through all my 10,000+ courses and generating a drop-down, but this is slowing down my website tremendously.

```
    <select class="custom-select" name="courses[]" multiple="multiple" id="courses" required>
    @foreach (Facades\App\Course::course()->take(30) as $course)
    <option value="{{ $course->id }}">{{ $course->course }}</option>
    @endforeach
    </select>
```

I'm unable to figure out how to optimize this drop-down. Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A 10,000+ options select sounds like a bad idea. Why would you want that?

Comment: No matter what, rendering 10,000 `<option>` elements is going to slow down your system... Consider a live-search (Enter X characters, then get a list from an AJAX request, etc) or similar approach.

Comment: @jrswgtr the idea is to have the users select multiple courses. 10,000+ options select is definitely a bad idea, but I don't know what else to do. I'm thinking of a dynamic approach where I query based on the characters in the search bar, like what the live-search Tim mentioned

Comment: Yeah Tim's approach should be your go.